# How to create an Assembly Mips program which counts binary 1 in an ASCII string

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm pretty new on assembly Mips programming, I'm feeling more comfortable in C, but I want to learn this language.

I'm thinking about a program that counts the number of binary 1. For example, hexadecimal code for the letter "e" is 0x65, in binary 0b1100101.
My program if the letter "e" is received as an input, in output will have "4" in decimal, which is the number of binary 1 for "e".

I think that I need logic bitwise instructions for this, because I'm not working with byte but with single bit.

How can I do this?

Comment: Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight#Efficient_implementation and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21959118/counting-1s-in-an-integer-using-mips-assembly-language-without-any-flow-of-con .

Answer (score 2):

If I remember well, the fastest way to count bits at 1 in an integer is the SWAR algorithm :

```
int swar(uint32_t i) {
  i = i - ((i >> 1) & 0x55555555);
  i = (i & 0x33333333) + ((i >> 2) & 0x33333333);
  return (((i + (i >> 4)) & 0x0F0F0F0F) * 0x01010101) >> 24;
}
```

You can translate it into assembly by searching appropriate MIPS instructions for logical shifts, ands and so on...

Comment: Probably so.  MIPS and MIPS64 gcc5.4 turns `__builtin_popcount` into a function call, instead of inlining anything: https://godbolt.org/g/H0rEWX.  Of course, I didn't enable any `-march` options; maybe some MIPS CPUs have a popcnt in hardware?  There's also a MIPS SIMD extension, right?  If it has a byte-shuffle, you might be able to use it like x86's PSHUFB to implement a 16-entry parallel LUT for up to 16 nibbles in parallel.  (i.e. up to a 64-bit integer)